# Remove last name suffix with javascript recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

I want to write a function that takes names like this...

```
Dan Smith Jr
Kim Johnson II
Dr Jones PHD
Bill Clinton
```

And returns the last name...

```
Smith
Johnson
Jones
Clinton
```

My solution is to chop the final word off a string, compare it to a stop words array, and recursively loop until a word isn't in the stopword array...

```
var fullNameArray;
var lastName;
var suffixArray = ["jR","Jr","JR","jr","I","II","III","i","ii","iii","PHD","PHd"]; //list of stopword prefixes

function getLastName(fullName){
    fullNameArray = fullName.split(" ");
    lastName = fullNameArray[fullNameArray.length - 1]; //got the last word

    if (suffixArray.indexOf(lastName) == -1) {
        //it's NOT a suffix so RETURN the name
        console.log("returning last name of: " + lastName);
        return lastName;
    } else {
        //it WAS a suffix so call the function again with the last name chopped off
        fullNameArray.pop(); //remove the last item
        getLastName(fullNameArray.join(" "));
    }
}
```

My problem is that the recursive call doesn't work as expected:

getLastName("Dan Smith") correctly returns:

```
 "returning last name of: Smith"
 "Smith"
```

getLastName("Dan Smith Jr") returns...

```
 "returning last name of: Smith"
 "undefined"
```

What mistake am I making for the return not to work from within a recursive call?!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to return the result of recursively calling the function:

```
return getLastName(fullNameArray.join(" "));
```

Comment: oh man - that's painful - thanks/sorry (I'll accept as answer in 5 minutes)